# Recent (>=3.5) version of Hibernate with JBoss 4?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, classpath

Is this actually possible and are there any instructions around for it?

I've read a lot around specifying the classloader and using java2ParentDelegation as false in my jboss-app.xml and moving jars out of (or into) the JBoss server lib directory. But I haven't found anything conclusive and I've not been able to get past class loader related issues (classes not found or incompatible).

Thanks in advance (and no, I can't change the JBoss version sadly)!

Comment: Which version of JBoss 4?  You can use the version of Hibernate you want with 4.0.2, but its incompatible with 4.2.3.  If you're on 4.0.2, all you need to do is add the Hibernate dependencies and you're good to go.  4.2.3, you're out of luck.

Comment: @AaronSheffey Why is it incompatible?

Comment: Hibernate comes pre-installed with newer versions of JBoss, and the version installed on 4.2.3 is older than 3.5, and that version of Hibernate causes issues for JBoss 4.2.3, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the class loading issues with hibernate in jboss server you need to **add the `jboss-classloading.xml` inside the `WEB-INF` folder of your web application.** Read more about these configuration settings [here](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/).

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
domain="pentaho.ear"
export-all="NON_EMPTY"
import-all="true"
parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

Comment: That's for JBoss 5+, isn't it? The OP's question, however, was for JBoss 4.